# Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

So, I have the code like this:

```
        const voiceid = message.member.voice.channelID;
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(voiceid);
        channel.join().then(connection => {
            function loopa(connection) {
                const dispatcher = connection.play('./audio/1.mp3');
                dispatcher.on('finish', loopa(connection));
            }
            loopa(connection);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
```

and after the first run (play the audio), instead of looping, it return the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
at StreamDispatcher.loopppp (E:\discordbot\index.js:144:36)
at StreamDispatcher.emit (events.js:327:22)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:639:14)
at _stream_writable.js:616:5
at StreamDispatcher._final (E:\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\dispatcher\StreamDispatcher.js:248:5)
at callFinal (_stream_writable.js:609:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I tried define the argument inside `play` with a const but that didn't work.
Edit: google didn't help much

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to include the code that defines `connection` since that is the source of the error. Also, if you could add indentation and simple variable names it would be better. If you have any further doubt, you can check the [ask] page

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there might be a conflict between the two connection variables. Try this:

```js
        channel.join().then(connection => {
            function loopa(c) {
                const dispatcher = c.play('./audio/1.mp3');
                dispatcher.on('finish', loopa(c));
            }
            loopa(connection);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed it like [this](https://pastebin.com/hHpWw9M9) but it's return like [this](https://pastebin.com/FQVFJ9Q9). It's running on heroku.